# deserialize POCO array with JsonFX

Tags: c#, json, poco

I want to simply read some JSON data from a URL, then turn that into an collection of POCO classes, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a sample of the JSON data, as it is fetched from the URL:

```js
[
{
"Name":"Together As One Run",
"Location":"Parkville, MO",
"ScheduledAt":"\/Date(1334984400000)\/",
"URL":"http://www.runningintheusa.com/Race/View.aspx?RaceID=36667"
},
{
"Name":"Lean Green Running Machine 5K Run/Walk and 1 Mile Run",
"Location":"Springfield, MO",
"ScheduledAt":"\/Date(1335589200000)\/",
"URL":"http://www.runningintheusa.com/Race/View.aspx?RaceID=53945"
},
{
"Name":"Festival of Miles",
"Location":"St. Louis, MO",
"ScheduledAt":"\/Date(1338440400000)\/",
"URL":"http://www.runningintheusa.com/Race/View.aspx?RaceID=53901"
},
{
"Name":"Miles Against Melanoma",
"Location":"Saint Charles, MO",
"ScheduledAt":"\/Date(1338613200000)\/",
"URL":"http://www.runningintheusa.com/Race/View.aspx?RaceID=53939"
}
]
```

I can get this data with WebClient just fine.

I'm setting up my JsonFX reader like this:

```cs
var json = new JsonReader(new DataReaderSettings(new PocoResolverStrategy()));
```

Here is my POCO class:

```cs
public class Race {
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public String Location { get; set; }
  public DateTime ScheduledAt { get; set; }
  public String URL { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to deserialize JSON data in several ways, and nothing seems to work:

```cs
//reader is an instance of StreamReader
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
//nope
//var output = json.Read<Race>(content);
//nope
//var output = json.Read<Race[]>(content);
```

This has got to be a simple thing to do, I just can't find a solution.  I spent about 30 mins. googling to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used JsonFX but you can try [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) or built-in `JavaScriptSerializer`. Both work without any problem.

```
 var jObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Race[]>(jsonstr);
 var jobj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Race[]>(jsonstr);
```

Comment: I ended up using the JavaScirptSerializer and it worked like a charm.  I tried several other suggestions here but JsonFX did not work with any of them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*edit* oops, didn't read the title. Why are you using jsonfx? 
maybe try a list?

```
var output = json.Read<List<Race>>(input);
```

Here is a valid example of how to get it done with JSON.Net.

You're going to want to use JSON.NET. It's faster than any of the built in classes and does a much better job of serializing dictionaries.

using Nuget

`> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

```
List<Race> deserializedRaces = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Race>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to specify the datacontract and datamember attributes on your custom type for jsonFX to recognize it.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract]
public class Race {
  [DataMember]
  public String Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public String Location { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime ScheduledAt { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public String URL { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell it to try parsing your date as a Microsoft-style date time:

```
var jsonReader = new JsonReader(
    new DataReaderSettings(
        new PocoResolverStrategy(),
        new MSAjaxDateFilter()));
```